# How to fecth data from database for archive in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

i am facing a critical issues. I am trying to retrieve the data from database for archive but data doesn't show perfectly. I wrote the following script but that is not working. please help me the fix this issues.

**Following this script i am showing the month and year like (August2023)**

```
    @foreach ($archive as $data)
            
                <p><a href="<?php echo url('/');?>/detailsarchive?m={{$data['month']}}&. y={{$data['year']}}">{{$data['month'].''.$data['year'] }}</a></p>  
  @endforeach
```

**Following script is route.**

> Route::get('detailsarchive/{m}/{y}/', [FrontendController::class,
> 'detailsarchive'])->name('detailsarchive');

Following this controller doesn't show any kind of result.

```
 public function detailsarchive($m,$y)
{
              
      $posts = Journalform::latest();
      
      $posts->whereMonth('created_at', $m);
      
        
     if($y = request('year')){
          $posts->whereYear('created_at', $y);
      }
    
      $posts = $posts->get();
   
     return view('Frontend.Date.allviewpost', compact('posts'));    
    }
```

Comment: You did not tell us what's wrong with your code, so we cannot tell you what to change.

Comment: `&. y={{$data['year']}}` doesn't look like a valid url and certainly doesn't look like the route you defined

Comment: your `if($y = request('year')){` makes no sense

Comment: fyi, you use `==` or `===` to compare. `=` _assigns_ a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're showing a Laravel route declaration for a GET request that points to a method detailsarchive within the FrontendController class. This route has two parameters {m} and {y} which are placeholders for the month and year, respectively. The name() method is used to give the route a named reference that can be used to generate URLs in your application.

Here's a breakdown of what this code does:

Route::get('detailsarchive/{m}/{y}/', [FrontendController::class, 'detailsarchive']): This defines a GET route that listens for URLs in the format detailsarchive/{m}/{y}/, where {m} and {y} are placeholders for the month and year. When a request matches this URL pattern, the method detailsarchive within the FrontendController class will be executed.

->name('detailsarchive'): This assigns a name to the route. Naming routes is useful when you want to generate URLs for this route in your views or code using the route() helper function.

So, in your views or code, you can generate URLs for this route using the route() helper like this:

```
$url = route('detailsarchive', ['m' => $month, 'y' => $year]);
```

Replace $month and $year with the actual month and year values you want to use in the URL.

Remember to ensure that the FrontendController class has a method named detailsarchive that handles the logic for this route.

```
@foreach ($archive as $data)
   <p>
     <a href="{{route('detailsarchive',['m'=>$data['month'],'y'=>$data['year']])}}"> 
            {{$data['month'].$data['year'] }}
     </a>
   </p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i cant understand $url = route('detailsarchive', ['m' => $month, 'y' => $year]); how to work this. Please could you write the perfectly route.

Comment: I would suggest reading the docs first: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes @PhoneFashion

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method `detailsarchive($m,$y)` you are compacting `posts` and in your view, you are trying to for-each loop on `$archive`. That is inconsistent. Try changing the `$archive` to `$posts` in your view:

```php
@foreach ($posts as $data)
    <p><a href="<?php echo url('/');?>/detailsarchive?m={{$data['month']}}&. y={{$data['year']}}">{{$data['month'].''.$data['year'] }}</a></p>
@endforeach
```

**Side Note:**
Don't assume that `Laravel` will also contain `archive` like in `WordPress`

Comment: I have already show the month and year. I am trying to show the post list under the each month. i think this possible. Just i am facing the following script. Could you correct this ?
 public function detailsarchive($m,$y)
{
              
      $posts = Journalform::latest();
      
      $posts->whereMonth('created_at', $m);
      
        
     if($y = request('year')){
          $posts->whereYear('created_at', $y);
      }
    
      $posts = $posts->get();
   
     return view('Frontend.Date.allviewpost', compact('posts'));    
    }

Comment: @PhoneFashion update your question with specific problems or issues you are facing